# All news or all of the news

Tags: word-choice

Should I use the definite article before "news" in the second and third sentences? Isn't it wrong to use 'from" instead of "on" in the first sentence?

1. You can read news reports on a Telegram news channel. 2. All news are about contemporary art. 3.I think that's good, because almost all news lately is about the coronavirus.

Can I also use "all of the news" in 2 and 3?

This is one passage but I devided it into several sentences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*News* has become an uncountable noun in English; a single piece of information is 'a news item' or 'a piece of news'. *The news* can also mean a regular news bulletin on radio or TV.

Obviously it's not true that *all* news is about art, but you could say 'all today's news' or 'all the news today *is* about contemporary art'.

I would use *the news* in (3) as well (and probably *has been*).

Comment: Would it be wrong to use "all of the news?"

Comment: No, that wouldn't be wrong.

Comment: "I don't read news. The news turned into gossip. News builds a distorted picture of the world. The solution is simple. Don't read the news and live in peace." Is "the" optional in my examples and is it optional when talking about the news generally?

Comment: Do you mean in 3 "almost all the news" would be wrong without "the"?

Comment: But you don't need to say "of." You can say "all of the news," but saying "all the news" means the same. I agree with what @KateBunting said, that for #2, you could say "all today's news *is*," or "all *the* news *is*," but not "all news is" since, clearly, "all news *is not* about contemporary art," as you demonstrate in #3. Since, as Kate aptly pointed out and intimated with her italicized "*is*," "news" is a noncount noun, be sure not to say "news *are*," which I don't want to escape your attention since you wrote "news *are*." Finally, you don't need "the" before "coronavirus" in #3.

Comment: In your examples, _news_ is news reporting in general, while _the news_ can refer to a particular news story, a particular day's news or a particular news broadcast. So _almost all news_ isn't wrong, but it implies 'most of the whole range of news reporting'.

Comment: Thank you both so much for your answers!!

Comment: But in case all news was about one thing, would "all news" be correct? It's unlikely but still if something  was really happening.

Comment: _All news_ is grammatically acceptable, but unlikely. Even when the world's news media are concentrating on one story, as with 9/11, we would probably say that it 'dominates the day's news'.

Comment: Can I rephase your explanation and say "news" without an article refers to general news but with the article to sprcific news.  I can choose either "the news" or "news" depending on what I mean.  I mean in the sentences below. I can choose to say "the news" or "news".

1. "I don't read the news." Specific. Without the definite article "I don't read news" general news.

2. "The news turned into gossip." 

3. " The News builds a distorted picture of the world." 

4. "The solution is simple. Don't read the news and live in peace."

5. "You can read the news on a Telegram news channel."

Comment: I mean in each sentence I can use "the news" or "news".

Comment: I don't see a lot of difference in meaning in those particular sentences, except that I understand (2) to refer to one particular news story.